# Portability libraries/frameworks

Tags: c++, c, frameworks, portability

I have the book "Write Portable Code" which details [POSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poshlib), an open-source "framework" (mostly just a header) to help with portability of C/C++ code between different platforms and hardware.

Since Poshlib hasn't had an update in 5 years now, I was wondering what other similar libraries/frameworks exist out there?

Answer (score 4):

For C code, GLib is a modern cross-platform (non-GUI) library which makes it easy to write applications that run on many different platforms without source code changes. GLib is actively developed in an open manner as part of the GNOME project with lots of open source projects using it.

For C++ I would suggest looking at the Boost libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Dear Shaggy Frog,
While I remain largely incurious about your handle, I must say that this is something of a hairy issue.  Here's why.  I work with the boost libraries day in and day out.  They're fantastic, and make innumerable tasks way easier.  But I must emphasis that if you use them, you need to use a profiler.  Some of the really nice portions of it tend to be a bit slow, and you should definitely read up on best-practices before using certain parts like, say, transform iterators.  Boost, though, is worth mentioning because it does make an effort to supply some pretty powerful pieces of abstraction that are almost foreign in the ++cverse.

However, Boost, and other frameworks like it, are not snakeoil.  They rock.  People who rock use them.  People who rock work on them.  For more specialized tasks, I'd need to know more about your problem domain.  However, one other tool that's really excellent is SWIG, which will let you bundle up any hunk of portable C code into a library that's... well.... accessible.

As for bloat, a lot of that is going to go away when C++0x moves to the standard, thanks to variadic templates, and a number of similar pieces of cleverness.  Honestly, I'm tired of people yelling about *The Terrors Of Templates.*  Perhaps six years ago they were a danger due to poor compiler support, but these days, they're part of the language.  They live under almost every piece of generic code you touch.  Projects like CLang are hammering the very last nails into this coffin as we speak.  They aren't a fad anymore.  They aren't a magical solution.  No one still thinks that.  No one you should hire, anyway.

The future approaches.  Do you need a Boost?

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries with the buzzwords "portability framework" or "portable runtime" in their names are useless bloat and snake oil. If you want to write portable code, start with the relevant standards and follow them. Instead of reading your vendor's man pages or help files for standard library functions, read the ISO C or C++ standard or POSIX standard. And so on.

Aside from highly crippled embedded systems (note: many/most embedded systems do not fall into the "highly crippled" category) and DSPs, pretty much any environment can be made to be POSIX conformant. A much better approach than trying to design or find a new "portability framework" on top of diverse and incompatible underlying systems is to evaluate what parts of POSIX you need to get the job done, what parts might be missing or non-conformant on systems you're interested in, and whether there are drop-in replacements or workarounds for the missing or broken functionality.

For most people, the only relevant non-POSIX system is Windows. Cygwin is one heavy-weight option for making Windows conform to POSIX, but if you code to a more-inclusive subset of POSIX, you can get by with much lighter solutions and still support Windows.

Comment: Having worked at a Large Video Game Company developing AAA titles, I can tell you that "header frameworks" like these go a *long* way to improving code reuse and readability, so I don't understand how you can dismiss them all as "snake oil". Perhaps you are talking about something different than me, but projects like POSH allow developers to spend more time writing better code and spend less time worrying about things like endianness.

Comment: If your code is affected by endianness, it's broken (dependent on IB or UB to begin with). Writing portable code in the first place would be a lot better than slapping a "portability framework" band-aid on it. As for types, C99 has all the fixed-size types you need. If you find yourself on a pre-C99 platform that's missing `stdint.h`, simply write your own utilizing the right types for that platform and drop it in your compiler's standard include directory.

Comment: And to elaborate, this is a big part of what I mean by coding to the standards. The (C and C++) standards say if you want to deserialize data from disk/network, you perform arithmetic working a byte at a time, rather than relying on matching type sizes, endianness, and struct alignment...

Comment: Dealing with data an octet per time is portable, but inefficient on modern platforms (even portable devices have 64 bit architecture, tens of cores in GPU and about terabyte of storage). That wheel has been researched to death. The libraries with common interface on platform-specific implementations are freely there and work and that is not snake oil. On the contrary, it is usually yet another square wheel char* math lying around that causes these endianness, alignment and size issues.

Comment: Most large game data is audio, video, and images, which anyone sane will compress with a bitstream/bytestream oriented compression scheme. And reading small data has trivial impact on performance, even if your compiler isn't smart enough to convert byte-at-a-time arithmetic into word-sized loads and possibly bswaps.

Comment: I fail to see how endian-ness can be avoided by processing something a byte at a time.  What if that stream started as a stream of ints or similar arithmetic data?  Like, say... I don't know... oh!  Vertices.

Comment: Something like `x = buf[0]*256+buf[1]; y = buf[2]*256+buf[3];` Note that this is a really simplistic example. In the real world you'd have macros/functions like `get_uint32`, `get_float32`, `get_vertex`, etc. that pull and assemble the bytes and advance a pointer or index in the buffer accordingly. And you might use some sort of compression or variable-length coding.

Comment: "If your code is affected by endianness, it's broken" is a great soundbite, one of those positions that sounds great in theory but does not hold up in practice

Comment: Unless I can't read, I'm not sure how the posted code is safe from Endian mishaps.

Comment: @Jake: It has identical behavior on any machine, given the same input octet stream. If you can't read C, SO is here to help. @Shaggy: It works great in practice. While naive game coders who learned from snakeoil $60 "optimization" books with CDs in the back go around doing nonsense like reading into binary structures, everyone else (including people in high-performance fields like video codecs) is moving towards or already doing everything in the right, portable ways.

Comment: @R.. Your position is ideological and not pragmatic or realistic. Just as one example, dealing with endianness of data is a huge concern in all sorts of software, not just video games. I don't see how one could write C code that works on any hardware/platform reading bytes from a socket without, at some point, needing to handle endianness. By your definition, the entire C socket library is broken because it has functions like `ntohl`!

Comment: @R..: I can read C.  What I meant was that your code merely transcribed the data.  Sooner or later, you may need to use that data.  And then, you care about the endian nature of it.

Comment: My code did not transcribe data. It deserialized two 16-bit unsigned integers out of an octet stream.

Comment: And it does so by copying the octets, which we sometimes call bytes, into temporary variables.  It in turn does this by placing the leading byte into the high and the trailing byte into the low.  How do you know that the leading byte was the high byte?

Comment: @Shaggy: `ntohl` was a (or rather *the*) huge design mistake in sockets. Everyone competent agrees on this. Nonetheless, as long as your code correctly *uses* `ntohl` where needed, it's not endian-dependent. Your code has identical behavior on little- and big-endian machines due to the fact that it's using portable interfaces for conversion rather than blindly using data off the network as local types.

Comment: @Jake: It's part of the specification for your serialization format. If you're designing the format, you can choose whatever you want as long as you write and read it portably. If somebody else designed it, you have to follow their spec.

Comment: @R..: Okay, now I'm curious.  I've never heard it referred to as The Huge Mistake, but I'm not entirely in disbelief.  Can you point me towards some opinion articles?  It'd make interesting reading, I think.

Comment: @Jake: I've seen it mentioned multiple times in network-related topics on SO, by some of the most respected (in terms of rep) site members. I suspect there are articles/papers/blog posts but I haven't run across them. Basically the issue is that for the sake of a tiny kernel optimization, every userspace app was forced for all time to store non-natively-readable "integer" values in socket address structures, greatly amplifying the complexity of working with such structures.

Comment: If I'm understanding R correctly ("as long as your code correctly uses ntohl where needed, it's not endian-dependent" and "It's part of the specification for your serialization format. If you're designing the format, you can choose whatever you want as long as you write and read it portably"), then my definition of endian dependent is not the same as his.  In fact, my definition of endian dependent is exactly what he says is good.  He just likes to do the endian packing/unpacking by hand.

Comment: @Max: My definition of "endian dependent" is code which has measurably different behavior (or requires different special-cased code to achieve the same behavior) dependent on the endianness of the host machine. My view is that properly written code will never be "endian dependent" under this definition.

Comment: @R:  I guess my definition is sloppy.  Because, really, my definition isn't about the code but about the data:  when code deals with multibyte data type from outside the machine that code must be written to handle endian issues as soon as the endian-dependant *data* is read into the machine.  But when I write it out like that, it seems pretty obvious and exaclty like what you've been saying (you've also been saying that low level bit fiddling that can fail or at least be slow because of endianness issues is broken).

Answer (score 0):

There is similar [Predef](http://predef.sourceforge.net/index.php) project on sourceforge, but it are not updated for several years also.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the predef pages are actively maintained and have been continuously updated over the last several years.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Boost, which all C++ programmers should be familiar with, there are several libraries worth looking at.  [STLSoft](http://www.stlsoft.org/) is the first one that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared [a list of some prominent portability libraries](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/portability-libs/) for C and C++ on my personal web site. One can freely reuse it under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution Licence. I had some experience with Qt, GLib, and the Apache Portable Runtime, and they all seemed to have been mostly OK.

There is also [another list on the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform#Cross-platform_programming_toolkits_and_environments).